# Loop en EDGE javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un ciclo interminable en el explorador edge y la verdad no puedo encontrar la falla en mi código, me gustaría saber si alguien me pudiera a indagar en el!?

Esta función es disparada en un onBlur y valida que que el input no sea vació

```
function validate(element, message) {
if (element.attr('id') == "tel" || element.attr('id') == "cel") {
    if (element.attr('id') == "tel") {
        if (element.val() == "" && $("#cel").val() == "") {
            message.show();
            return 1;
        } else { message.hide(); return 0; }
    } else {
        if (element.val() == "" && $("#tel").val() == "") {
            message.show();
            return 1;
        } else { message.hide(); return 0; }
    }

} else {
    if (element.val() == "" || element.val() == null) {
        element.focus();
        message.text("Este campo es Obligatorio");
        message.show();
        return 1;
    } else {
        message.hide();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

esta otra función esta en una acción onClick y mando a llamar cada uno de los campos que valido

```
function validacion(num) {
switch (num) {
    case 1:
        var x = 0;
        x = x + validate($("#nombre"), $("#nombreMes"));
        x = x + validate($("#app"), $("#appMes"));
        x = x + validate($("#fechaN"), $("#fechaNMes"));
        x = x + validate($("#rfc"), $("#rfcMes"));
        x = x + validate($("#perfil"), $("#perfilMes"));
        x = x + validate($("#cel"), $("#telMes"));
        x = x + longitud($('#imss'), $('#imssMes'), 19,1);
        x = x + longitud($('#curp'), $('#curpMes'), 19, 1);
        x = x + longitud($('#rfc'), $('#rfcMes2'), 14, 1);
        if (x < 1) {
            var block = $('<div class="block-loading" />');
            $('body').prepend(block);
            $("#personal").removeClass("active");
            $("#hogar").addClass("active");
            $("#goFam").trigger("click");
            setInterval(function () {
                block.hide();
            }, 300);
        }
        break;
```

Tengo más cases pero este es el unico que me da el error.
Cabe mencionar que solo me falla en EDGE. En Chrome u opera, no da problema

Comment: trata de abrir en las opciones de desarrollo de EDGE (creo que es tambien por F12 o Ctrl + i para Mac), la parte de la consola a ver que te dice. Puede ser que estes utilizando algo que EDGE no soporta.

Comment: Falta el html y el sitio donde agregas el handler para el evento click. Sin eso no se puede saber que pasa. En base a lo que hay yo miraría esta linea `$("#goFam").trigger("click");` de la función `validación`. Eso está disparando un evento click por código y si a su vez el handler de click llama a `validacion` entonces tenemos un loop.

Comment: Hola @IsaacVega el error que manda EDGE es un desbordamiento en la pila con el error **SCRIPT2343**. eso es lo que muestra la consola.

Comment: @derloopkat la linea `$("#goFam").trigger("click");` solo es detonada si el   `if (x < 1)` es ejecutado lo que en mi logica , creo que si es asi, no?